# Is there a way to use an animated gif as ImageBrush's ImageSource?

Tags: c#, wpf

The following code works, but the loaded gif isn't animating. It looks like the imagebrush uses the gif's first frame for displaying. I'd like to get the gif moving if it's possible.

```
string imagePath = $"pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/{imageName}.gif";
return new ImageBrush()
{
    ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath)),
    TileMode = TileMode.Tile,
    ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
    Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE),
};
```

Comment: there is no direct way of doing this in wpf . you'll have to use third part library

Comment: Do you have a reccomendadtion for that?